# WSGI error with Google Endpoints Tutorial

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm trying to run [this Google Endpoints python tutorial](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine/standard/endpoints/backend).

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "main.py", line 19, in <module>
        import endpoints
      File "/home/mica/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/endpoints/__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
        from .apiserving import *
      File "/home/mica/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/endpoints/apiserving.py", line 81, in <module>
        from protorpc.wsgi import service as wsgi_service
    ImportError: No module named wsgi
```

The error clearly comes from a python library. How am I supposed to fix the issue?

Comment: Looks to be a duplicate of this issue discussed in the Google product forums: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-cloud-endpoints/_M__MCBnJVw

Answer (score 0):

That "tutorial" doesn't correspond to any tutorial from the Google Endpoints team. The [official tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/python/get-started-frameworks-python) uses [this](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine/standard/endpoints-frameworks-v2/echo) instead.

Answer (score 0):

I just came up against the same problem in the ['hello world' tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/protorpc/#The_Hello_World_of_ProtoRPC) for ProtoRPC.

As indicated by your error traceback, an ImportError occurs when Endpoints tries to import the `protorpc.wsgi` module, which is missing.

It turns out that the `protorpc.wsgi` module has been missing for some time. There's a [pull request from 2016](https://github.com/google/protorpc/pull/21) that should have fixed the omission, but for some reason it was never merged. I've left a comment there, which is probably just about all we can do.